# How can i import SQLite db3 file

Tags: php, sqlite

Sorry about this question but i never worked with SQLite, and i gone through the SQLite site , downloaded "Precompiled Binaries For Windows" files tried to make them usable for my purpose but i couldnot, i saw with working tutorials with databases,tables.

My tasks is to get data from SQLite and put them into magento mysql DB. So for that i have got the SQLite  DB dump file as .db3 file, txt file which has size of db dump file(20110125_SIZE).

So how can i import it into the SQLite. Please if anyone of you worked with SQLite3 help me to understand the .db3 file and how can i see the records from them.

I have got sqlite3 db dump as dbname.db3,

So then i tried to connect this sqllite from php. Here is my sample code which i got it from forum.

```
    $db = openDatabase();   
    unset($db);

    function openDatabase() {
        $dbFile = realpath('dbname.db3');
        echo $dbFile . "\n";
        $needDbCreate = !file_exists($dbFile);
        $db = new SQLiteDatabase($dbFile) or die((file_exists($dbFile)) ? "Unable to open" : "Unable to create");
        if($needDbCreate) {

        }
        return $db;
    }
```

But i am getting fatal exception.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'SQLiteException' with message
>   'SQLiteDatabase::_*construct() [sqlitedatabase.--construct]:
>   file is encrypted or is not a
>   database' in
>   C:\wamp\www\SQLITE\index.php:23 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\SQLITE\index.php(23):
>   SQLiteDatabase->*_construct('C:\wamp\www\SQL...')
>   1 C:\wamp\www\SQLITE\index.php(15): openDatabase() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\SQLITE\index.php on line
>   23

But when i tried the same sqldump with the PDO , i got connected.

```
try {       
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:C:\wamp\www\SQLITE\dbname.db3");
        echo 'Db Connected <br/>';

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

here i do not know the list of tables available in this dump so how can i query them to list and then getting records from them.

Please help me to solve this issue ti get connected and browse the tables from php.

> Sorry for posting here in answer
>   section, i wanted to highlight the
>   code.

Thanks

Comment: Edited my reply to cover the part of the question that should have been edited into your original question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a system where SQLite is installed, you will usually also have the `sqlite3` command line program. It can be used both from the command line or in interactive mode to dump data or load it into a (binary) database file.

```
sqlite3 ./database.file
```

This will give you the interactive prompt, where you can issue SQL commands or special commands such as `.help` or `.dump`.

There are also more graphical tools, but they are probably overkill for what you want to do.

Edit: seeing your reply (currently in the answer section), it seems that your .db3 file simply is not in the binary SQLite3 format, but instead perhaps a dump. That would be a problem. If it is a dump, you'd have to load it into a proper database file first.

```
cat yourdump.sql|sqlite3 ./realdb.db3
```

Comment: @Ela: alright, so the file was an actual binary format SQLite3 database?

Answer (score 0):

```
call three times 
$rr=exec("sqlite3 database.db \".separator '|'\" ");
$rr=exec("sqlite3 database.db \".import myfile.txt tablename\" ");
$rr= exec ("sqlite3 database.db \"pragma encoding = 'utf-8'\" ");

or 
single line 
$rr=exec("sqlite3 database.db \".separator '|'\" && sqlite3 database.db \"pragma encoding = 'utf-8'\"   && sqlite3 database.db \".import myfile.txt tablename\" ");
```